# Drawing text on a Bitmap (rather than Canvas)

Tags: android

I am drawing some text on a Canvas, and on a Bitmap, respectively:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText("Canvas text", 10, 10, mPaint);
    Canvas singleUseCanvas = new Canvas();
    singleUseCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
    singleUseCanvas.drawText("Bitmap text", 10, 30, mPaint);
}
```

In the former case, the text renders as you would expect, while in the latter, it appears very rough and ugly. This becomes even more problematic when using e.g.

```
canvas.drawBitmapMesh(...);
```

to apply transformations to the bitmap. Am I doing something wrong, or is the quality simply deteriorated when you pass from Canvas to Bitmap?

On a side note, the reason why I'm drawing text on a Bitmap is to obtain a "magnifier" effect on the text in question (like Apple OSX's dock), since I can then apply arbitrary transformations to it using a bitmap mesh. Is there another, perhaps better, way to do this?

Best,

Michael

**Edit:** Solved. For those interested, the problem seems to occur when using API versions < 4. When using API versions >= 4, everything works.

Comment: Don't forget to turn on Anti-alias on your `Paint` that you draw text with.  Available since API 1.